# Reconstructing missing information from game results

Tags: python

I have a dataset of results from games of n players, where each game has n-1 players playing. The results of a game may look like this:

```
1 2 _
_ 1 2
2 _ 1
```

where each column represents the results of 1 player. However, the dataset has been corrupted and columns where players have a bye (_) have been collapsed so that results turn out like this:

```
1 2 2
2 1 1
```

I currently have python code to take in the results from a file and add them to an numpy array, which includes a function to insert a bye into a column. Printing the array gives this output:

```
[['1' '2' '2']
 ['1' '1' '2']
 ['0' '0' '0']]
```

I am struggling to figure out how to find the corrected results, especially if some collapsed results may have multiple solutions. I know I need to use a recursive solve () function, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Here is my current source code:

```
import numpy as np

collapsed_results = []
p = 0


def insert_bye(grid, row, column):
    for i in reversed(range(row, p)):
        if i == row:
            grid[i][column] = "_"
        else:
            grid[i][column] = grid[i - 1][column]

    return grid


def solve(collapsed_results):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            line = input()
        except EOFError:
            break

        line = line.split(" ")
        collapsed_results.append(line)

    # Number of players
    p = len(collapsed_results[0])

    collapsed_results.append([0] * p)
    collapsed_results = np.array(collapsed_results)
```

Comment: Do you know in which game which player did not participate and just want to recreate the proper array, or do you have to find that out first? Are there other constraints, e.g. (as it seems) each game awarding scores from `1` to `n-1` to the players?

Comment: @tobias_k I don't know which game the player did not participate in, so sometimes multiple results are possible. There is no way around this. The scores are simply the player's position in that game i.e., 1 = first place

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
from collections import deque
def pad_col(d, l, c=[]):
   if len(c) == l:
      yield c
   else:
      yield from ([] if not d else pad_col(d[1:], l, c+[d[0]]))
      if l - len(c) > len(d):
         yield from pad_col(d, l, c+[0])

def solve(collapsed, l = 3):
  def combos(d, c = []):
     if not d:
        yield list(zip(*c))
     else:
        for i in pad_col(d[0], l):
           yield from combos(d[1:], c+[i])
  return list(combos([*zip(*collapsed)]))
       
print(solve([[1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1]]))
```

Output:

```
[[(1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0)], [(1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)], [(1, 2, 0), (2, 1, 2), (0, 0, 1)], [(1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0)], [(1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1)], [(1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 2), (0, 1, 1)], [(1, 0, 2), (2, 2, 1), (0, 1, 0)], [(1, 0, 2), (2, 2, 0), (0, 1, 1)], [(1, 0, 0), (2, 2, 2), (0, 1, 1)], [(1, 2, 2), (0, 1, 1), (2, 0, 0)], [(1, 2, 2), (0, 1, 0), (2, 0, 1)], [(1, 2, 0), (0, 1, 2), (2, 0, 1)], [(1, 2, 2), (0, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)], [(1, 2, 2), (0, 0, 0), (2, 1, 1)], [(1, 2, 0), (0, 0, 2), (2, 1, 1)], [(1, 0, 2), (0, 2, 1), (2, 1, 0)], [(1, 0, 2), (0, 2, 0), (2, 1, 1)], [(1, 0, 0), (0, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1)], [(0, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1), (2, 0, 0)], [(0, 2, 2), (1, 1, 0), (2, 0, 1)], [(0, 2, 0), (1, 1, 2), (2, 0, 1)], [(0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)], [(0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 0), (2, 1, 1)], [(0, 2, 0), (1, 0, 2), (2, 1, 1)], [(0, 0, 2), (1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 0)], [(0, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 1, 1)], [(0, 0, 0), (1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1)]]
```